# Rearrange columns by name and number in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns like this for example (as 1 being any values to simplify things here:

```
         ID    App R1    Pear R1    Oro R1   App R2   Pear R2    Oro R2    App R3   Pear R3   Oro R3
0         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1        1
1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1        1
```

I would like to rearrange the columns like this:

```
         ID    App R1    App R2    App R3   Pear R1   Pear R2    Pear R3    Oro R1   Oro R2   Oro R3
0         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1        1
1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1        1
```

I have tried:

```
df.columns = [['ID'] + ['App R{}'.format(r+1)] + ['Pear R{}'.format(r+1)] + ['Matched fragment ions R{}'.format(r+1)] + ['Oro R{}'.format(r+1)] for r in range(len(files))]
```

n.b: The number r of App, Pear and Oro will depend on the number r of csv I start with

However, no success so far.

Thank you if you can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, for a better visual comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use custom `sorted` with lookup key

```
In [4291]: look = {'I':0, 'A':1, 'P':2, 'O':3}  # order for letters 

In [4292]: sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: look.get(x[0], ''))  # first letter key
Out[4292]:
['ID',
 'App R1',
 'App R2',
 'App R3',
 'Pear R1',
 'Pear R2',
 'Pear R3',
 'Oro R1',
 'Oro R2',
 'Oro R3']

In [4293]: df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: look.get(x[0], ''))]
Out[4293]:
   ID  App R1  App R2  App R3  Pear R1  Pear R2  Pear R3  Oro R1  Oro R2  \
0   1       1       1       1        1        1        1       1       1
1   1       1       1       1        1        1        1       1       1

   Oro R3
0       1
1       1
```

Comment: I was so close to this one I was using first 3 letters to create dict and was failing. This is super

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Zero! I just have one little problem when using it. I have three last column (which I didn't add in the example I gave) which have the same first and second letter (e.g. Apr R1 Apr R2 and Apr R3) and I tried to put the whole column name instead of just the first letter and unfortunately it failed like Bharath sherry stated in his comment below. Do you think you have another solution? Much appreciated

Comment: Then use it for 3 characters like `look.get(x[:3], '')` after updating `look`

Answer (score 1):

I think `MultiIndex` should help:

```
#set all not R columns to index
df = df.set_index(['ID'])
#create multiindex
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
#custom reordering
df = df.reindex(columns=['App','Pear','Oro'], level=0)
print (df)
   App       Pear       Oro      
    R1 R2 R3   R1 R2 R3  R1 R2 R3
ID                               
1    1  1  1    1  1  1   1  1  1
1    1  1  1    1  1  1   1  1  1
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(' '.join)
print (df)
    App R1  App R2  App R3  Pear R1  Pear R2  Pear R3  Oro R1  Oro R2  Oro R3
ID                                                                           
1        1       1       1        1        1        1       1       1       1
1        1       1       1        1        1        1       1       1       1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried it for my code but only works for 'App' and not the other one. And is it normal to have 'NaN's after the R1 and before the values ?

Comment: I cannot simulate it

Comment: But basically it depends what you need. MultiIndex can help for some operations, e.g. if need working with all `Oro` columns together e.g. some arithemtic operations. If not, nicer is use another Zero answer.